# How do I inject Web3 into Remix IDE?

Tags: solidity, remix

when going on to the remix IDE, i get the error

No injected Web3 provider found. Make sure your provider (e.g. MetaMask) is active and running (when recently activated you may have to reload the page).

after trying to switch the environment on Remix IDE from JavaScript VM to injected web3. I tried using a http connection as well and it didnt work. I am trying to inject web3 into remix IDE using MetaMask and I cannot switch my environment to injected web3 because of the error I mentioned above. All help is appreacited, thank you.

ANSWER:

Once I switched to FireFox the web3 was injected. The web3 only worked on firefox

Comment: Are you logged into Metamask? Did you reload the page as indicated? In Metamask's settings/Connections check if remix.ethereum.org is authorized, if not try "Remove all sites" to clear previously authorized/unauthorized sites.

Comment: yes logged into MetaMask, reloaded the page, and also added remix.ethereum.org as authorized, and removed all sites and added it back and it still didn't work.

Comment: It is a strange behavior, try another browser. For me it works without issues on latest firefox (76). If problem persist you should report to Metamask's developers in their github repo.

Comment: thank you, once I switched to FireFox the web3 was injected. I'll make a comment on MetaMask's repo.

Comment: Sometimes it is enough to change https into http in Remix's URL.

Comment: Did u ever figure this out having same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue. Using HTTP instead of https solved. hape this might help.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing a similar kind of problem when I am injected web3 on remix ide. if you want to solve this problem you must be active on your metamask account before injecting web3.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For me I had to remove meta mask from chrome, and then reinstall it. I read that updating meta mask might work too. But I could not find an option on my version to upgrade. so Had to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, when i opened both remix ide and metamask in chrome it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, when i install metamask once again in chrome and restart remix ide it worked.